# Nil pointer dereference behavior when reading from stdin

Tags: string, go, pointers

Here is my Go program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    . "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    testBool *bool
    myName   *string
)

func main() {
    testBool = flag.Bool("testbool", false, "test bool flag")
    flag.Parse()
    Println(*testBool)
    funcFlags()
}

func funcFlags() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    Print("Enter your name: ")
    *myName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    Println(myName)
}
```

Its execution ends up with a nil pointer dereference error as shown below:

```
▶ go run main.go -testbool
true
Enter you name: John
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x10acc9e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.funcFlags()
        /Users/pantelis/Desktop/cli_testing/main.go:25 +0x1de
main.main()
        /Users/pantelis/Desktop/cli_testing/main.go:19 +0x13b
exit status 2
```

Why the assignment

```
*myName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
```

errors out as above, while this one

```
testBool = flag.Bool("testbool", false, "test bool flag")
```

succeeds.

Both variables (i.e. `testBool` and `myName`) are initialised the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
*myName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Means to assign a value to where the `myName` pointer points to. But it doesn't point to anywhere, its value is `nil`. You can't dereference a `nil` pointer, that's a runtime panic as you experienced.

`testBool` is **not** initialized the same way.

```
testBool = flag.Bool("testbool", false, "test bool flag")
```

Here `testBool` is not dereferenced, `flag.Bool()` returns a non-`nil` pointer which is assigned to the `testBool` variable, and **not** to the pointed value.

To make your app work, `myName` must point to somewhere. You have to initialize it, e.g. with the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function:

```
myName = new(string)
*myName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Or don't use pointers, just declare `myName` to be a non-pointer:

```
var (
    testBool *bool
    myName   string
)


// ...
myName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
```

In Go you can't access uninitialized memory. If you don't expicitly provide an initial value for a variable, it will get the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of its type. Zero value of `string` is the empty string `""`, but your original `myName` is a pointer, and zero value for pointers is `nil`.

See related question:

[Go pointer first assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019680/go-pointer-first-assignment/38019987#38019987)

Comment: but if a variable __is not explicitly initialised__ doesn't it get its __default__ value? (in this case `""` since we are talking about a string ) and therefore its allocated somewhere in the memory and so the pointer gets an address? (that was my initial assumption)

Comment: @pkaramol They get the zero value (not default). And your `myName` is a pointer, its zero value is `nil`. Pointers cannot have a value of type `string`, so the empty string cannot possibly be the zero value of your `myName` variable. See edited answer.